# Managing pairs of files as an individual

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

I know that Windows Explorer has the ability to manage pairs or groups of files as a single entity, at least with HTML files saved using Internet Explorer.

I'd like it to handle other pairs in a similar manner; specifically, I'd like to hide the "XMP" files that Photoshop saves alongside "CR2" image files (essentially, it contains the metadata for how the Canon Raw image was opened/developed).

Is there a registry tweak that would allow this behaviour, or would I need Canon or Adobe to implement all sorts of COM interface magic?

Comment: This may fare better in Stack Overflow...

Comment: I did wonder that myself...

Comment: Seems a related question has been asked at: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5957/21

Comment: Short Answer: No.  Related question: http://superuser.com/questions/239039/associating-grouping-a-file-with-a-folder-in-windows-so-that-they-both-are-moved

Comment: @afrazier there must be *some* way, for it to work with HTML files saved; even if it is via some COM interface

Comment: AFAIK, no, it's not possible to extend Explorer to allow for this.  It's a feature that's been hardcoded into the Explorer shell, and there's no COM interface by which it can be extended.  I'm about to update my answer in the related question I linked to...

Answer (score 1):

No. it's a windows feature created by microsoft specifically for ofline website files. it's a hardcoded feature in explorer that checks to see if you are moving a .htm/.html file. If you are explorer will look for a matching folder of the html file name with an extra "_files" and move that folder automatically.

It's nothing special. You can try it yourself. Make a blank "test.htm" file on your desktop. then make a folder named "test_files". drag and drop either the html file or the folder and watch as it moves the other one.