# Associating/Grouping a file with a folder in Windows so that they both are moved together

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ntfs

I saved an HTML web page using Google Chrome. An HTML file along with a folder containing the images was saved on my computer. Now when I move the HTML file to a different location or delete it, the folder moves along with it.

How is this association enforced?

I am seeing this behavior on Windows. Is it something specific to NTFS? Can it also be achieved on Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/41200/302

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is specific to the Windows shell, and applies *only* to .htm and .html files.  If you'd moved the file from a Command Prompt, the associated folder would stay in place.  In Windows XP, this behavior is controllable via Tools -> Folder Options in an Explorer window (or the Folder Options icon in the Control Panel).  On the View tab, under Advanced settings is a group of options labeled "Managing pairs of Web pages and folders".

The GUI option to change this behavior appears to be gone from Windows 7; I'm not sure about Vista.

The feature can be managed via the registry.  The key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`, DWORD value `NoFileFolderConnection`.  Disable the feature by setting the value to 1.  Re-enable the feature by setting the value back to 0 or deleting the value altogether.

The feature itself is called `Connected Files`, and a reference is available at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776887.aspx#connected).

To extend this feature beyond just HTML pages and their associated folders, you'd have to implement everything yourself.  [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164.aspx) already has special support for connected files, but there doesn't seem to be any means by which to extend it.

Since the feature is shell-dependent, it'd have to be recreated in the file managers in Linux.

Comment: I am using Windows 7. And there must be a way to establish it programatically as Google Chrome is doing it for the saved HTML files.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: Nope -- it's driven *entirely* by the file/folder names.  Updated my answer with more information and references.  I'm curious what the downvote was for though, for whomever did that.