# HTML + Folders auto moving together - how to apply to other files

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Associating/Grouping a file with a folder in Windows so that they both are moved together](https://superuser.com/questions/239039/associating-grouping-a-file-with-a-folder-in-windows-so-that-they-both-are-moved)

If you save an HTML using a browser like Chrome with "Webpage Complete" selected, Chrome will save both the HTML, and a folder which has in it all the resources that HTML uses (images ect).

When you move/copy the HTML to another place on your pc (say a flash drive) then the folder will copy too, and vis versa.

My question is this: Why does this happen? And is there anyway to "apply" this on other files, for example with disc images such as .mdf + .mds (which cant work with one another)

Comment: Are you sure? Once you save it, they are separate files and folders. You can move them individually. Just tried and works.

Comment: @Bibhas I can confirm this behavior on Windows 7 and Google Chrome. I've never noticed before. They do move together for some reason...

Comment: @iglvzx Windows 7 here too. Did not work. I can move around the html files individually. As it should be.

Comment: I can confirm this on Windows XP (Clean install, virtual machine) with IE, FF, and GC. There must be an underlying feature/standard that is causing this. Here is something that hints that `<filename>_files` folders are special folders: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2637230

Comment: @iglvzx Yes. Chrome and Windows 7. I think there might be an option somewhere that switches on this behavior.

Comment: Thanks all! It does seem a shame that you cant apply it to other files without ease, but oh well. Sorry bout the duplicate question!