# Adding a 'connected file' link to an Excel Workbook

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, windows-explorer, file-management

This is fairly specific, and I'm not sure if it can be done, but thought I'd ask.

When you save a web page in Windows, you get the HTML file, and a folder called '[Title of webpage]_files'. The folder and the HTML file are bound, so if you move the file anywhere, the folder goes too. This is known as 'Connected Files'.

Is there any way to do this with other file types? A look through Microsoft's documentation says not, but I didn't know if anyone had any ideas? I'd like to link a folder of resources to an Excel Workbook, so that the document always knows where they are, even if the workbook is moved.

Any help or alternative ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/239039/associating-grouping-a-file-with-a-folder-in-windows-so-that-they-both-are-moved

Comment: The reference to your inquiry is above in my previous comment. But if you write VB code, you can "hard code" the location of the "resource folder". You could add a command button, [Connect Resources] and link it to the piece of VB code. You could also leave the file with the resource folder and create a shortcut. Wherever you move the shortcut, the file will still know where it is and the folder it references as resources.